# Compiling all non-zero values in a row into a string column

Tags: r

I have a sparse design matrix-like dataframe that looks like this:

```
  BRDirect BRExclusive MagnetY MagnetN Reasons
1     0.00        0.17    0.08    0.00      NA
2     0.00        0.00    0.08    0.00      NA
3     0.00        0.17    0.00    0.06      NA
4     0.29        0.00    0.00    0.06      NA
5     0.29        0.00    0.00    0.06      NA
6     0.00        0.00    0.00    0.06      NA
```

And I want to write a function that can be applied to each row to populate the `Reasons` column with the all non-zero values in that row accompanied with the column name of that value, separated by " / ". So,

```
  BRDirect BRExclusive MagnetY MagnetN                             Reasons
1     0.00        0.17    0.08    0.00 BRExclusive (0.17) / MagnetY (0.08)
2     0.00        0.00    0.08    0.00                      MagnetY (0.08)
3     0.00        0.17    0.00    0.06 BRExclusive (0.17) / MagnetN (0.06)
4     0.29        0.00    0.00    0.06    BRDirect (0.29) / MagnetN (0.06)
5     0.29        0.00    0.00    0.06    BRDirect (0.29) / MagnetN (0.06)
6     0.00        0.00    0.00    0.06                      MagnetN (0.06)
```

The length of this "reasons" string will vary row-to-row.

Here's the function I'm currently using:

```
find_reasons <- function(order){
  reasons <- NA

  for(col in names(order)){
    # check if column value is non-zero and the column isn't the "reasons" column
    if(order[col] != 0 & col != "Reasons"){
      # paste column name and value
      vals <- paste(col," (",order[col],")",sep="")

      # either populate "reasons" or add to it
      reasons <- ifelse(is.na(reasons), vals, paste(reasons, vals,sep=" / "))
    }
  }

  return(reasons)

}

test$Reasons <- apply(test, 1, find_reasons)
```

But when I apply this to my actual data (446030 rows and 171 columns) with apply(), it's so slow it never finishes. I think this is because my function loops over each column for each row, but I can't think of how to do this since each row can have a different combination of filled columns.

Is there a better way to do something like this?

Comment: Two reasons I suspect your function is not performing well: (1) `apply(test, ...)` is causing the entire matrix to be converted to a `matrix`; this is normally a fast operation, but since there are `character` in at least one column then all columns are *also* converted to `character` before your function sees them; (2) when possible, vectorize your operations, as @akrun did (with `x1` within the anonymous function) in his answer. No need for a `for` loop.

Comment: @r2evans Yeah, I get that. I try to avoid `for` loops as much as I can yet I clearly still don't have an understanding of how almost everything can be vectorized. One of the things I'm struggling with most in this language. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I agree it can be confounding, but once you start "grokking" how to think vectorizing thoughts, so much code can be simplified, easier to read (logically), and almost always sped-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could do this with `apply` from `base R`

```
df$Reasons <- apply(df[1:4], 1, function(x) {
           x1 <- x[x!=0]
           paste(names(x1), " (", x1, ")", sep="", collapse=" / ")})
```

Comment: What an elegant solution. I definitely struggle understanding when things can be vectorized, I never would've thought of this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Didn't know apply would keep the column names!

Comment: @snoram. It does, that is the one of the advantages though it have many disadvantages

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to

1. reshape the dataset from wide to long format (perhaps restricted to those columns which are relevant),
2. omit all zero values, and
3. create the `Reasons` string by row number.
4. Finally, the result column will be joined back into the original dataset (using an *update join* to prevent copying).

using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
reasons <- melt(setDT(test)[, rn := .I], id.vars = "rn")[
  value != 0.0][
    , paste(sprintf("%s (%3.2f)", variable, value), collapse = " / "), by = rn]
test[reasons, on = "rn", Reasons := V1][, rn := NULL]
test[]
```

> ```
>    BRDirect BRExclusive MagnetY MagnetN                             Reasons
> 1:     0.00        0.17    0.08    0.00 BRExclusive (0.17) / MagnetY (0.08)
> 2:     0.00        0.00    0.08    0.00                      MagnetY (0.08)
> 3:     0.00        0.17    0.00    0.06 BRExclusive (0.17) / MagnetN (0.06)
> 4:     0.29        0.00    0.00    0.06    BRDirect (0.29) / MagnetN (0.06)
> 5:     0.29        0.00    0.00    0.06    BRDirect (0.29) / MagnetN (0.06)
> 6:     0.00        0.00    0.00    0.06                      MagnetN (0.06)
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
test <- fread(
  "i  BRDirect BRExclusive MagnetY MagnetN Reasons
1     0.00        0.17    0.08    0.00      NA
2     0.00        0.00    0.08    0.00      NA
3     0.00        0.17    0.00    0.06      NA
4     0.29        0.00    0.00    0.06      NA
5     0.29        0.00    0.00    0.06      NA
6     0.00        0.00    0.00    0.06      NA",
drop = c(1, 6))
```

Answer (score 2):

version using function and apply by row:

```
   reason <- reason[, -ncol(reason)]
   res_Names <- colnames(reason)
   def_res <- function(a){paste(paste0(res_Names, " (", a, ") ")[a!=0], collapse = "/ ")}
   Reason_res<- apply(reason, 1, def_res)
   reason <- cbind(reason, Reason_res)
```